# How to Add a url Image to a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

edit 
[image]

[image]

I use the code below to add a background image to a `JPanel`, problem is I can't figure out a way to add an image to a `JButton`.. any ideas?

```
    public void displayGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Painting Example");


    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(440, 385);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);

    JButton button = new JButton("want picture here");
    panel.add(button);


    button.addActionListener(new Action7());
}

class Custom4 extends JPanel {

    public BufferedImage image;

    public Custom4() {
        try {

            image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://i68.tinypic.com/2itmno6.jpg"));

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Unable to fetch image.");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return (new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics x) {
        super.paintComponent(x);
        x.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [the `JButton` `Icon` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html#JButton(javax.swing.Icon)), and pass it an [`ImageIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html).

E.g. instead of

```
JButton button = new JButton("want picture here");
```

do

```
JButton button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(new URL("http://i68.tinypic.com/2itmno6.jpg")));
```

Since the URL constructor throws a `MalformedURLException`, you'll also need to wrap this in a try-catch block (and put your button use statements in there as well). To scale it, you also need some [extra calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810213/java-stretch-icon-to-fit-button). Additionally, you can remove the visible parts of the button completely, by [removing border and content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898584/java-using-an-image-as-a-button). Since you have a `JPanel` behind the button, you'll need to set that to be transparent as well. The full code is below:

```
try {
    JButton button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon(
        new URL("http://i68.tinypic.com/2itmno6.jpg"))
        .getImage()
        .getScaledInstance(64, 64, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)))));
    button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    panel.setOpaque(false);
    panel.add(button);

    button.addActionListener(new Action7());
} 
catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // exception handler code here
    // ...
}
```

64x64 are the image dimensions here, simply change them to the desired dimensions for your image.

Answer (score 3):

It is much more simple: use an [icon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html#JButton(java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.Icon))

```
new JButton(new ImageIcon(youImage));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new URL(url));
JButton button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(img));
```